# DCS Service on HTC Desire Z

Tags: htc-desire-z, data-monitoring

I installed [My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) to see how much data traffic my phone generates and I noticed that there's some "DCS Service" using on average 180MB (!) per month.

DCS Service is not something I installed. It is listed under apps but I cannot uninstall it. 
Anyone got an idea what it is and how I can stop it from producing all that data traffic?

Comment: Solved it by replacing the HTC software by the Cyaogenmod rom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked htc what it is about and they responded with:

> The DCS Utility services and components are the programs on your
>   telephone that allow connection to the internet provided by your
>   mobile carrier. It stands for Data Connection Service.

A little vague. It also cannot be removed, they told me. And as the sense ui was constantly crashing I decided to install cyaogenmod. Best decision ever: not only is my data usage halved, the user interface is stable as a rock.